# IdentityServer4 and external oauth privider: The oauth state was missing or invalid

Tags: oauth, identityserver4, .net-5

I'm trying to implement external oauth authentication within IdentityServer4.
All auth requests goes successfully. I have a message AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in. in app log.
But when authentication process tries to go back to ExternalLoginCallback action it falls with Error 500 (**The oauth state was missing or invalid**) after HTTP 302.
[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97wlr.png)

1. Result 302. Request https://localhost:5999/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?state=xxx&code=xxx&session_state=xxx
2. Then request goes to https://localhost:5999/Account/ExternalLoginCallback (without any parametres)

My IS4 **Startup**

```
IdentityServerConfiguration.AddIdentityServer(services, _configuration);

        services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddTinkoff(_configuration)
            .AddSber(_configuration)
            .AddEsia(_configuration);
```

**AddTinkoff** extension method:

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddTinkoff(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IConfiguration config)
    {
        return builder.AddOAuth("TinkoffId", "Tinkoff ID", options =>
        {
            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://id.tinkoff.ru/auth/authorize?response_type=code";
            options.TokenEndpoint = "https://id.tinkoff.ru/auth/token?grant_type=authorization_code";
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://id.tinkoff.ru/userinfo/userinfo";
            options.CallbackPath = "/Account/ExternalLoginCallback";
            options.ClientId = "xxx";
            options.ClientSecret = "xxxx";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new TinkoffAuthorizingHandler(new HttpClientHandler(), options);
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "name");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email", ClaimValueTypes.Email);
            options.ClaimActions.MapAll();


            options.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                 
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                    request.Headers.Add(
                       HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(),
                       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    );

                    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",options.ClientId),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret",options.ClientSecret)
                        });

                    var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var user = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    context.RunClaimActions(user.RootElement);
                },
                //OnTicketReceived = async context =>
                //{
                //    context.HttpContext.User = context.Principal;
                //    //context.SkipHandler();
                //}
            };
            //options.Scope.Add("profile");
            //options.Scope.Add("email");
            //options.Scope.Add("phone");
        });
    }
```

My **ExternalLogin** action:

```
[HttpPost]
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"External login fired. ReturnUrl='{returnUrl}'. Provider='{provider}'");
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }
```

ExternalLoginCallback action not fired while debug.

What I'm doing wrong. Why request redirects to itself without params?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved an issue for me.
I added

```
OnTicketReceived = async context =>
                {
                    context.HttpContext.User = context.Principal;
                    //context.SkipHandler();
                    context.ReturnUri += $"/{context.Request.QueryString}";
                }
```

Now it works as expected